# Looping through file extensions, excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an Array of File extensions and looping through a folder of workbooks. The code is naming Sheet(1).name="MyName"

I notice that even though `"*.xlsm"` is not in the array, it is still opening and naming the sheet.

### [image]

Here's the code. Can anybody see if they get the same problem and are able to solve it.

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

    Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim fExt, ext
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    'change the address to suite
    MyDir = "C:\TestWorkBookLoop\"
    ChDir MyDir
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
    fExt = Array("*.xlsx", "*.xls")    'file extensions, set the file extensions of the files to move

    For Each ext In fExt    'loop through file extensions
        MyFile = Dir(MyDir & ext)


        Do While MyFile <> ""
            Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
            Sheets(1).Name = "MySheet"

            With ActiveWorkbook
                .Save
                .Close
            End With

            MyFile = Dir()
        Loop
    Next ext
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The legacy short (8.3) file name for `HELLO.ABCD` would look something like `ABCDEF~1.ABC` - see the extension is truncated to 3 characters.

In your case `GET.XLSM` would be `ABCDEF~1.XLS` and this [8.3 form is also matched](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883) by the Win32 API `FindFirstFile` (which is what `Dir()` calls under the hood) when you specify `*.XLS`

Just filter out the exceptions in you loop with

```
If Not UCase$(MyFile) Like "*.XLSM" Then 
    ....
```

Comment: Good answer. Suggest add the other file types as well

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to use the extension array in case I wanted to add more extensions.

Answer (score 3):

While Alex has solved your query, I have updated your code below to

- ensure it handles all excel file types
- handle the sheet name already existing (else your code will error out)
- cleanup and properly use variables
- restore events at close

  ```
  Sub LoopThroughFolder()

  Dim Wb As Workbook
  Dim MyFile As String
  Dim MyDir As String
  Dim StrFile As String


  MyDir = "C:\temp\"
  ChDir MyDir

  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .DisplayAlerts = False
  End With

  StrFile = "*.xls*"

  MyFile = Dir(MyDir & StrFile)
      Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
          If MyFile Like "*.xlsx" Or MyFile Like "*.xlx" Then
              Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
              On Error Resume Next
              Wb.Sheets(1).Name = "MySheet"
              On Error GoTo 0

              Wb.Save
              Wb.Close False
          End If
          MyFile = Dir()
      Loop

  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .DisplayAlerts = True
  End With

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to use the extension array in case I wanted to add more extensions.---Using your example:
When I add `Like "*.csv"` and step through the code, it opens the file and names the worksheet, but does not save it. Could be a .csv issue though

Comment: Davesexcel it doesn't  save but it closes?

Comment: Yes, when I step through the code the .csv file will open, change the sheet name, it does pass over the `.save` line then closes the workbook. When I open the CSV workbook, the sheet has not changed, indicating it did not save.

Comment: @Davesexcel interesting, I can duplicate this with a CSV although it works fine as I tested on xlsx etc. will investigate further.

Comment: That's okay the question has been answered. The .csv was just an observation. I am sure it has something to do with saving a .csv. When you do it manually, you are asked if you want to save it in that format. Possibly that dialog defaults to "No", so when we `displayalerts=0` then it won't save.--Thanks