# VB6 Dir("*.dot") globbing finding .dotx on one server but not the other

Tags: windows, vb6, glob

I have a very strange issue, that I hope someone else might know about.

I have a VB6 containing the following code

```
Dim filename As String: filename = Dir("c:\somepath\*.dot")

Do Until filename = ""
    ...add filename to listbox

    filename = Dir()
loop
```

When I run the exact same program on one Windows Server 2012 R2 (call it Server A), Dir() will return only files ending on .dot.

On a different Windows Server 2012 R2 (Server B), **Dir() will additionally return files ending on .dotx**

Both servers have Microsoft Office 2013 Standard edition. Both servers have AFAICS the same settings in File Explorer.

Server A locale is English
Server B locale is Danish

Are there any registry settings, that could make file globbing behave like this? I am thinking specifically about DOTX being the new Office template format?

Comment: B is the expected behaviour (.dot and .dotx) see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764765/looping-through-file-extensions-excel-vba) for why (8.3 names) - Or are you saying thats *not* happening on A and it should as both file types are present?

Comment: @AlexK. On Server A _only_ .DOT files are returned, even though the folder also contains .DOTX files

Comment: does `dir /x c:\somepath\*.dot` show .dotx files in the rightmost column? If so what is the short file name in the preceding column?  If it does not show .dotx does `dir /x c:\somepath\*.dotx`

Comment: Also the hidden attribute would hide them if its set on the files.

Comment: On server B (showing both extensions), dir /x c:\somepath\*.dot show long names as .dotx, but the shortname column is empty - on all files

Comment: Try reversing the *disable 8.3 name creation* procedure here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121007

Comment: We will try this - thank you so far, I'll get back to you with the results

Comment: You could also try `dir /x c:\somepath\*.dot*`, which should get all files whose extension begins with `dot`.  At least in old versions of DOS, the lack of an asterisk at the end would exclude any files whose extension wasn't an exact match of the string.  Perhaps this rule varies from OS to OS; I don't know.

Comment: I just performed a mini-experiment from the command line in Windows 7, and also from XP.  I tried `dir *.doc` and got both .doc and .docx files.  I tried `dir *.do` and got neither.  I tried both `dir *.do*` and `dir *.doc*` and got both.  Probably Microsoft changed the Dir command at some point to include extra extensions beyond 3 characters, if 3 characters were included in the filter.  Maybe because .htm and .html files started floating around everywhere.  Also maybe that doesn't apply in the Danish locale. Nevertheless the old rule that goes back to DOS 1.0 probably applies anywhere.

Comment: [This post](http://superuser.com/questions/825615/windows-wildcards-with-files-having-more-than-3-characters-extensions) has some interesting background, having to do with the old DOS short file names.

Comment: @AlexK. it worked - thank you very much. Could you please supply an answer about the _disable 8.3 name creation procedure_ then I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing would occur if the creation of 8.3 file names were disabled on the file system of the machine that does not list the `.docx` files.

You can re-enable this feature using fsutil by reversing the instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121007).

Comment: Thank you once more :-) This was way beyond my knowledge of internal Windows workings

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. Without being able to control the settings on every machine I ran my app on, it was easier to just deal with it in my code. I used FileSystemObject to iterate the files in the folder and compare the extension of the file to the extension I want to filter by. It was more reliable that filtering using Dir().

```
Public Sub ShowFileList(folderToSearch As String, extensionToFind As String)
    Dim oFileSystemObject As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFiles As Files
    Dim oFile As File
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileExtension As String

    Set oFiles = oFileSystemObject.GetFolder(folderToSearch).Files

    For Each oFile In oFiles
        fileName = oFile.Name
        fileExtension = oFileSystemObject.GetExtensionName(fileName)

        If StrComp(fileExtension, extensionToFind, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print fileName
        End If
    Next oFile

    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFiles = Nothing
    Set oFileSystemObject = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    ShowFileList "C:\MyFolder", "dot"
End Sub
```

Comment: we will do that eventually, but right now it is not an option.